# Tomcat Connectors definition in server.xml file

Tags: java, tomcat7

I would like to understand Tomcat's connectors definitions in server.xml file. What is the difference between the following configurations:

```
    <Connector port="8080"
               protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               socket.directBuffer="true"
               redirectPort="8083"
               keyAlias="tomcat"
               enableLookups="true"
               connectionTimeout="60000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               server="NA"
               minSpareThreads="2"
               maxThreads="10"
               acceptCount="10"/>

    <Connector address="127.0.0.1"
               port="8080"
               protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               socket.directBuffer="true"
               redirectPort="8083"
               keyAlias="tomcat"
               enableLookups="false"
               connectionTimeout="60000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               server="NA"
               minSpareThreads="2"
               maxThreads="10"
               acceptCount="10"/>

    <Connector address="::1"
               port="8080"
               protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               redirectPort="8083"
               enableLookups="false"
               connectionTimeout="60000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               server="NA"
               minSpareThreads="2"
               maxThreads="5"
               acceptCount="10"/>
```

According to [Tomcat 8 connectors documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html) the address property should be used only when the server has more than one IP address. Usually this configuration leads to the next 2 exception during Tomcat startup (since all 3 connectors tries to listen on the same IP and port):

```
26/10/2015 10:07:56 SEVERE org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:437)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:429)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:743)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:457)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:576)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:599)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)

26/10/2015 10:07:56 SEVERE org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1-8080"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:437)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:429)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:743)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:457)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:576)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:599)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
```

There is any reason to define 3 connectors like above?

Comment: `There is any reason to define 3 connectors like above?` I think not.

Comment: All the three would start of at the same IP, localhost port 8080, the only possible reason could be if you need to start 3 connectors on 3 separate ports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't bind to the same TCP port multiple times unless *every* bind is also to a specific IP address. Your first `Connector` fails this test. The other two specify `address=`, which makes them valid.

> According to Tomcat 8 connectors documentation the address property should be used only when the server has more than one IP address

It doesn't actually say that, but it isn't relevant, as every host has at least two addresses: 127.0.0.1 and its real IP address. In your case 3, as you also have `::1`, the IPv6 loopback address.